# SDI application with txt file extension not typing text

Tags: mfc

I have created a SDI application with the document template as txt file.

But I am unable to type any text in the window. Whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting typing in the window depends on the type of CView-derived class you are using. Study the SUPERPAD and WORDPAD MFC samples.

Comment: You're right. I had to change the view class to CEditView and I can type text